# Como fazer um usuário logado apagar sua conta?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

O usuário acessa a página logado:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Bem vindo, '.$_SESSION['username'];
?>
<br /><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
```

Eu quero que ele aperte um botão ou link e isso delete sua própria conta (sem precisar digitar nada).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["button"])){
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=projeto",$username,$password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this     line
$del = "DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE id =".$_SESSION['id'];


if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Conta deletada com sucesso');  </script>";
}
else{
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Falha');</script>";
}

$dbh = null;
}
 catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
?>
```

Como faço?

Comment: Mesmo que seja fora do assunto, acredito que NUNCA deva apagar um usuário e nem mesmo conceder privilégios ao `user` do banco de dados para isso! Em seu lugar, você pode usar uma coluna `Status` ou `isDeleted` ou equivalente, por exemplo. Dessa forma se o usuário for "excluído" você compara se o "Status" está como excluído ou não, atualizando via `UPDATE`. Isso é extremamente mais seguro, em diversos fatores, um primeiro porque usuários podem se arrepender de ter excluído aquilo ou tiveram suas contas acessadas por terceiros, dessa forma você pode recuperar facilmente. ;)

Comment: Ok. Mas, se for para fazer deletar direto, como faria?

Comment: Acredito que não há nenhum erro, ao menos a query parece está correta,  mas também não uso PDO. Porém, você está usando `if(isset($_POST["button"])){`, portanto o `input` (ou `button`) deve ter o atributo  `name` definido para `button`. Por exemplo: `<form action='logout.php' method="post"><input name='button' type='submit' value='EXCLUIR'></form>`, o HTML mostrado contem apenas um `a`, que por si só já é incapaz de fazer um `POST`, se estiver usando o HTML citado para excluir, essa talvez seja a razão.

Comment: Ainda nada. Teria como você ser mais específico?

Answer (score -1):

```
            <?php
            session_start();

            if(isset($_POST["button"])){
            $hostname='localhost';
            $username='root';
            $password='';

            $user = $_SESSION['id'];

            try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=projeto",$username,$password);

            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this     line

            $del = "DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE id = :id";
            $deletar = $dbh->prepare($del);
            $deletar->bindValue(':id', $user);
            $retorno = $deletar->execute();


            if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Conta deletada com sucesso');  </script>";
            }
            else{
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Falha');</script>";
            }

            $dbh = null;
            }
             catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            }

            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Eu clico e não acontece nada. Será que tem algo a ver com a declaração do meu html? 

<input type="button" name="button" value="Deletar Conta">